# Struts2 struts.xml configuration file - defining global config item

Tags: struts2

In my struts2 application i want to define a global configuration part and want to use it where needed.
To clarify let me share one action definiton below;

```
<action name="do_login" class="xxx.actions.AuthAction" method="doLogin">
        <result name="success" type="json">
            <param name="noCache">true</param>
            <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
            <param name="excludeProperties">actionErrors,actionMessages,errorMessages,errors,fieldErrors,locale,texts,action,username,password,errorCode,errorMessage,session</param>
            <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
        </result>

        <result name="error" type="json">
            <param name="noCache">true</param>
            <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
            <param name="excludeProperties">actionErrors,actionMessages,errorMessages,errors,fieldErrors,locale,texts,action,session</param>
            <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

as you can see, in result definitions there are some repeating parts which are;

```
<param name="noCache">true</param>
<param name="contentType">text/html</param>
<param name="excludeProperties">actionErrors,actionMessages,errorMessages,errors,fieldErrors,locale,texts,action,username,password,errorCode,errorMessage,session</param>
<param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
```

i want to define this repeating parts globally at the beginning of struts.xml file and use it in each result definition like;

```
<result name="success" type="json">
    {include global definition here}
</result>
```

i know it is possible to split struts.xml by packages or actions, but i'm wondering it is possible to do above my need?

thx in advance for any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts2 doesnt have anything for global parameters though they have for global result type,

so you can very well have both success and error as global result and use them.

They have something called as [static parameters](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11.1/docs/how-do-we-access-static-parameters-from-an-action.html) which is for Action class but not for result type as you need.

Comment: thx @mprabhat. in my case in each action's success or error result type; `<param name="excludeProperties">` parameters can vary even most of them are same. so i think i must split my struts.xml file by different packages or actions. thx for your answer.

Comment: @ŞabanUlutaş yeah you can do that, you should also think if you can break them into functionalities